# Querying table foreach value in an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array which looks like this:

```
$array = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5');
```

Now I also have database table column which its value is an imploded value. Now I want to `find_in_set` for each of the array value to see if its in the column also. For instance:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('/*for each value in the array*/', column)"
```

So I can get the columns where each array value can be found.
Please how do I run this code

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET(column," . implode(',', $array) . ")"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by first `implode()` your `array` like this

```
$implode_array = implode(',', $array);
```

Then you run your query like this

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(column, '". $implode_array."')"
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I already solved the issue depending on what I was given earlier

Answer (score 0):

Use `implode()` - it can transform array into string.

The first parameter is the 'glue' that ties array values together.

Example:

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
echo implode(",",$array);
```

This one will print a string "1,2,3,4,5,6".